# Allow Apache config to use wordpress login to protect private directory on linux server

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, authentication

I have a private directory and WordPress directory on the server, is there a way to protect this private directory using the WordPress login page?
I will share the links of the private files to the WordPress users, but I don't want them to be able to download anything from this folder until they log in, so I protect the content of this folder.

I looked into [mod_dbd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html), I tried to connect to WordPress MySQL installation, but I was getting this error `Invalid command 'DBDriver', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`
I don't know if I am going in the right direction or no.

Can someone plz guide me?

Answer (score 0):

The method I follow was having a folder inside wordpress that has symlink to the outside folder, and protect this file through htaccess to require authentication.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder_u_want_to_protect/.* [NC]
 RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```