# Safety of using cookies for authorization

Tags: wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, authorization

I am developing a Woocommerce website. I need to restrict access to files within some folders to individual users based on products they have purchased. My server is Apache and I was going to use X-Sendfile and some custom PHP scripts to handle the authorization and content delivery but my hosting provider will not enable mod_xsendfile.

I came across this post ([Allow Apache config to use wordpress login to protect private directory on linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490262/allow-apache-config-to-use-wordpress-login-to-protect-private-directory-on-linux)) and I think that I can just make some custom cookies when a user visits a page on my website describing what they have authorization to view and then simply check for the presence of this cookie in my .htaccess file, similar to how the answer to the linked post above suggest.

I will be setting the cookies as HTTP only and SameSite=”Strict” with a relatively short expiration. Based on my understanding of how cookies work, this seems like it would be safe but my knowledge is rather limited on this. Is there any known way for a malicious user to fabricate cookies (to make it seem like they have access) or to make the browser ignore the HTTP only and SameSite=”Strict” properties of the cookies (for instance allowing a CSRF)?

Thanks in advance